# Cassandra SSL with IP

Tags: ssl, amazon-ec2, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I have two instances on AWS. One for Cassandra 2.2.5 (it should growth to cluster later) and one for my Java application. Now these nodes connects without SSL, so now I want to enable it.
I tried to follow few instructions but always have exceptions when I'm trying to connect to cluster with SSL from my app and from cqlsh too.

Looking on exception's I suppose that problem in node-names, because instructions are written for case when all computers (cassandra nodes, app-instance and my computer where I user cqlsh) have domain names. But I have only IP's for all nodes. And for Cassandra node I even use two IP: "public" and "AWS private". First I'm using for cqlsh and second for app-to-C* communication.
Of course I have also an URL like *"ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.aws-location-x.compute.amazonaws.com"* but I'm not sure it is good idea to use this url.

So, how I should create a keys&certificates to my case?

Comment: What exceptions do you get while trying to connect? Are there any exceptions in the server logs as well?

Comment: Client side. For example on cqlsh I got: Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'localhost': ConnectionShutdown('Connection <AsyncoreConnection(140315873685968) localhost:9042 (closed)> is already closed',)})

Comment: (of course, this exception happens when I'm logged in to cassandra instance with ssh)

Comment: I found that with SSL cassandra prefer IPv6, so when changed hostname I got: "Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'::1': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('::1', 9042, 0, 0)]. Last error: Connection refused")})"